# Module to return the result of a promise

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, module, return, export

I have a bunch of async calls I want to put in a module and use the result in another. But it seems there is no way to use a return value in an async call with promise/callback.

```
module.exports = function () {
  Promise.all(data_promises).then(/* do stuff with data */)
  // return data ?
}
```

In another module:

```
var getData = require('async-module')
var data = getData()
```

Is it even possible with separate modules?

---

The actual code:

```
module.exports = function () {

  agentsSheet.useServiceAccountAuthAsync(creds).then(function(){

    var data_promises = priceCols.map(function (col) {
      return agentsSheet.getCellsAsync(1, {
        'min-row': 2,
        'max-row': 30,
        'min-col': col,
        'max-col': col,
        'return-empty': false
      })
    })

    Promise.all(data_promises).then(function (data) {
      var rawData = _.flattenDeep(data)
      var priceOptions = {}

      _.forEach(rawData, function (item) {
        priceOptions[item.value] = (priceOptions[item.value] + 1) || 1
      })

      var priceOptionsSorted = _.sortKeysBy(priceOptions, value => -value)

      console.log(priceOptionsSorted);
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes, return the promise and use it as usual (`.then()`).

Comment: @ShanShan I forgot to mention I want to do do stuff with the data before I return it, and not to include the manipulation in the second module

Comment: Also, in the actual code it is a promise within a promise...

Comment: `Promise.all(data_promises).then(/* do stuff with data */)` is a promise (`then()` always return a promise) so you can put all manipulation in your module with no issue.

Comment: You're missing a couple of return, I'm posting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add 2 return:

```
module.exports = function () {
  // one
  return agentsSheet.useServiceAccountAuthAsync(creds).then(function(){
    var data_promises = priceCols.map(function (col) {
      return agentsSheet.getCellsAsync(1, {
        'min-row': 2,
        'max-row': 30,
        'min-col': col,
        'max-col': col,
        'return-empty': false
      })
    })

    // two
    return Promise.all(data_promises).then(function (data) {
      var rawData = _.flattenDeep(data)
      var priceOptions = {}

      _.forEach(rawData, function (item) {
        priceOptions[item.value] = (priceOptions[item.value] + 1) || 1
      })

      var priceOptionsSorted = _.sortKeysBy(priceOptions, value => -value);

      console.log(priceOptionsSorted);
    });
  });
}
```

Now, the required module is a promise:

```
var getData = require('async-module');
// then() will run when the Promise.all() is resolved
var data = getData().then(/* do some stuff */);
```

Comment: Huh, this works great, but I am confused: what is happening when I do  `return promise().then()` what exactly gets returned?

Comment: Like a said before, `then()` always returns a promise (so you can chain them: `then(fn1).then(fn2).then(fn3)`), your function now returns a promise :) When you add a return before `Promise.all()`, it becomes the returned promise instead of the default one `then()` return. There is a great article about promises: http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html Search for *Solving the puzzle* in this page, you can see the importance of adding a return when you chain promises.